# Apollo error link - Catching errors and rendering a custom React component

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, react-context

I'm trying to make my React components tree aware of any network errors that happen in my app. These errors are actually being catched like this:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
  const { cache } = operation.getContext();

  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message }) => console.log(`GraphQL Error: ${message}`));
    cache.writeData({ data: { error: { message: graphQLErrors[0].message } } });
  }
  if (networkError) {
    console.log(`Network Error: ${networkError.message}`);
    cache.writeData({ data: { error: { statusCode: networkError.statusCode } } });
  }
});

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  credentials: 'include',
  uri: config.apiGraphql,
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache,
    link: from([
      errorLink,
      httpLink,
    ]),
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });
```

My `onError` triggers on every graphql request and if there is any error, my actual approach is to write it to my Apollo local cache.

The problem is, I have no idea how to make a component that is being rendered somewhere in the middle of my tree aware of this.

I have a query to read this value, but it doesn't rerender when I write to cache.

The component is like this:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { GET_ERROR } from 'graph/query/Commons/common';

const ErrorHandler = ({ children }) => {
  const { data } = useQuery(GET_ERROR);

  console.log(data && data.error);
  return data && data.error
  ? (
    <Fragment>
      AN ERROR HAPPENED
      {data && data.error}
    </Fragment>
  )
  : children;
};

ErrorHandler.propTypes = { children: PropTypes.any };

export default ErrorHandler;
```

Of course, when it first renders, there is no error at all. Then I write to cache, but `ErrorHandler` never realizes this.

I have tried using `writeQuery` without success... maybe because I'm lacking a _id or __typename field?

Is there any other way to pass this error to my components?

My React version is 16.8.

Comment: I have been thinking about other options, like a React.Context that holds the `error` and `setError`. However, I'm not on a "component environment" at this "bootstrapping" part of my app so there is no way I can use a hook to set the values of that context.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, `writeQuery` was the way to go.

After some trial/error I reached this code for my `errorLink` which works perfectly:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation }) => {
  const { cache } = operation.getContext();

  if (graphQLErrors) {
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message }) => console.log(`GraphQL Error: ${message}`));
  }
  if (networkError) {
    console.log(`Network Error: ${networkError.message}`);
  }

  if (graphQLErrors || networkError) {
    cache.writeQuery({
      query: GET_ERROR,
      data: {
        error: {
          __typename: 'error',
          message: graphQLErrors[0].message,
          statusCode: networkError.statusCode,
        },
      },
    });
  }
});
```

All I had to do was to make Apollo aware of the change happening to the `GET_ERROR` query. That query is the same one my `ErrorHandler` component is using.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issues by setting `errorPolicy: 'none'` then you can catch graphQLErrors object from your component.

```
yourQuery(){
  return apolloClient.query({
    // your code
    errorPolicy: 'none'
  }).catch(({ graphQLErrors }) => {
    // handle here
  });
}
```